# Moving all activities from one record to another, SSIS or C#?

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We've recently installed Field Service on to our CRM.
This means we are now using Service Accounts(Accounts) and prior to this we used a Custom entity.
I want to move all activities over from this Custom entity to the new Service Account.
What's going to be the best way to do this? SSIS or writing a C# Console App perhaps?

Many thanks,
Christopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is generic and subjective. Let me try to add my 2 cents. There might be someone with more expreice who can add more details to your questions.

You asked specifically for 2 options

1. **SSIS:** Do you have license for any of SSIS product. If yes I would prefer this option. Reason: You will have connections already available and most of the SSIS products have drag and drop flows which will perform most of the generic logic. I have some experice with Scribe and I found it easy to use and faster to perform CURD operation.
2. **C# Console APP:** I do code most of my time and I am quite comfortable with C# code. Here the main drawback is you have to write most of the code may it be from connection to Dynamics to get records, perform all the CURD operation and write few lines of code. The more line of code the more chances of making mistake. It takes also some time to write code and test it. But main advantage is you have all the control and can perform most of the operations as you want.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I don't currently have a license for any SSIS product(s). So I was thinking C# may be the better route. But I wanted to see if there was an explicit reason not to use C#. Just so I can better write a question next time, what could I have added to make it less generic/subjective?

Comment: could you upvote answer if it helps and if it fines with you could you accept the answer.